# Integral of function

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find $\displaystyle\int {1\over s^2 (s-1)^2}\,ds$.

I'm not sure how to set the integral to something like $A/s^2+B/(s-1)^2$. I don't know when do we use $Ax$ and when do we use $Ax^2$ and when do we just use $A$.

Show thorough steps please?? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about [partial fraction decomposition](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx)?

Comment: You maybe need to decompose it as $\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s^2}+\frac{C}{(s-1)}+\frac{D}{(s-1)^2}$

Comment: When using partial fraction decomposition, the polynomial in any numerator of the resulting summands will be at most one less than the degree of the corresponding denominator's polynomial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{s^2 (s-1)^2}&=\left(\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}\right)^2=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}-\frac{2}{s(s-1)}\\&=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}-2\left(\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}\right)\end{aligned}$$
This gives
$$\int\frac{1}{s^2 (s-1)^2}ds=-\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s-1}-2\log\frac{|s-1|}{|s|}+C$$

Comment: Great shortcut, +1.